# How to return or get the timestamp from google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

please dont mind my ignorance. Currently I am a "Make your office life easier DIYer" and I am trying to build a pdf generator using GoogleForms, whereby, I had already successfully ran a script and produced a pdf file from it.

By using GoogleForms, and the answers to the questions are used to fill up a GoogleDoc template where it automatically changes/replaces the specified values in it. However, the dilemma I am having now is how to capture the 'Timestamp' created after submitting the form.

This was the code I am using:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info)
}

function createPDF(info){
 
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("19Mbse07Dh03SXhCMDCuUHwP1oNqfhul_");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ye9x0l_izDGku91g4ekxDMH8JDIyxdB1");
  const tempDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1p2nCjS4z_4MEGSud833DBRf9Lcby0zPWT_k3SjLiMoo");

  const newTempFile = tempDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder)

  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{q3}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{q1}", info['1. Description'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{q2}", info['2. Description'][0]);
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("My PDF")
  
  
}
```

The problem I have now is how to get the 'Timestamp' created after submitting a form.

The form successfully captures the "1. Description' and "2. Description" and changes the form in GoogleDoc template which I used to create the pdfFile.

I had followed the documentation under the "Form Submit", particularly namedValues to try to return the 'Timestamp'

```js
{
  'First Name': ['Jane'],
  'Timestamp': ['6/7/2015 20:54:13'],
  'Last Name': ['Doe']
}
```

The documentation, mentioned 'Timestamp', however I cannot extract it.

Can anybody help me out on this? I am certain that I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the timestamp use `e.namedValues["Timestamp"][0]`, i.e.

```
var timestamp = e.namedValues["Timestamp"][0];
```

I suggest you to spend some time learning about data structures in JavaScript (objects, Arrays)

Resources

- [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)